# how to control 405 response in laravel 8 and passport without token access front insomnia

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am building an API (my first api in this framework) in laravel 8 with passport 10 for accesses by token, to consult and test the API I use Insomnia, in insomnia I do the work environment with two variables "base" for the URL and "token".

When I test my API routes from Insomnia and pass the Token, it does not give me problems, the errors start when I remove the environment variable Token in Insomnia, the laravel API crashes with a 405 error (Method not Allowed).

[image]

My question is how can I control laravel so that when the user doesn't send the token my application doesn't crash?

I insist, this only happens when I remove the Token environment variable in Insomnia.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, i want to make sure that you are sending the `Accept` and `Content-Type`.

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Second, `MethodNotAllowedException` indicates that you calling the route with different HTTP verb as you can see supported method is `POST` and you are using `GET`.

Third, in order to catch the `MethodNotAllowedException` you can add in your `Handler.php` located at `app\Exceptions\Handler` in `report` method

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
   if ($request->ajax() && $e instanceof MethodNotAllowedException) {
       return response()->json([
           "Please enter your token"
       ], 405);
   }
        
   return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you helped me with headers section.